# Usar string.format para aliniamiento

Tags: c#

resulta que me preguntaba como puedo alinear con el string.format el result hacia la derecha 15 carácteres. Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera y no ha funcionado (se queda en el mismo lugar).
Adjunto el código:

```
using System;

    namespace Exercisi_random
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int a, b, result;
                Console.WriteLine("Insert first number:");
                a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert second number:");
                b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                result = (a + b) * (a - b);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,15}\n", "The result of the operation is: {0:f5}", result));
            }
        }

}
```

Este es el resultado que espero:

```
Insert first number: 2
Insert second number: 3
The result of the operation is:        -5.00000
Press any key.
```

Esto es lo que me da:

```
Insert first number: 2
Insert second number: 3
The result of the operation is:-5.00000
Press any key.
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el resultado que te da el programa y el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy sencillo. Solo necesitas especificar en la propia `string` los formatos que vas a aplicar:

```
Console.WriteLine("The result of the operation is: {0, 15:f5}", result);
// "The result of the operation is:        -5.00000"
```

Como ves, solo basta con indicar que el valor en índice `0` tomará todo ese espacio (`, 15`) y que además lo escribirá con determinado formato (`:f5`). También observa que `WriteLine` te permite formatear el texto igual que la función `string.Format`.